# Fiji (is just ImageJ) memory issue

Tags: memory-management, macros, imagej

Just a bit of background:

I have created a Fiji (is just ImageJ) macro that takes a folder of scanned images (of 6mm plates aligned in a 3 * 4 fashion) Identifies these ROI's (the plates) and separates them into individual images. These single images are then compared for difference image analysis and the results stored as excel spreadsheets. This is designed to be activated at the end of the day and be left overnight to process.

My issue is that the Fiji's memory slowly fills then throws an error, stopping the program. I have garbage collection in my code but it never fully clears the memory which is why is slowly fills to capacity.

I would really like this to work on most machines (so buying more RAM isnt really an option) I have on my current testing machine 8GB of RAM and 3/4 of that allocated to FIJI.

Below is the code where i believe the issue lies. (this is the last step of the macro where the individual images are compared) Any help is much appreciated :)

```bsh
function jakero(startdir, enddir){

    path = getFileList(startdir);
    for(i=0; i<path.length; i++){
        open(startdir+path[i]);
        print(path[i]);
        if(i%2){        
            run("Images to Stack", "name=stack1 title=[] use");
            wait(1000);
            //create the image difference between the sequential scans
            selectWindow("stack1");
            run("Image Stabilizer", "transformation=Affine maximum_pyramid_levels=4 template_update_coefficient=0.90 maximum_iterations=20000 error_tolerance=0.0000001");
            run("Collect Garbage");
            run("Z Project...", "start=1 stop=2 projection=[Max Intensity]");
            imageCalculator("Difference create", "stack1","MAX_stack1");
            selectWindow("MAX_stack1");
            wait(2000);
            run("Close");
            run("Collect Garbage");
            wait(100);
            selectWindow("Result of stack1");
            wait(2000);
            run("Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=2 stack");
            wait(2000);
            //for tif was 5000 3500
            run("Hysteresis...", "high=30 low=10");
            wait(8000);
            selectWindow("Result of stack1");
            wait(100);
            run("Close");
            wait(100);
            selectWindow("Hysteresis");
            wait(100);
            rename("Result of stack1");
            wait(100);
            run("Invert");
            wait(2000);
            run("Properties...", "channels=1 slices=1 frames=1 unit=mm pixel_width=0.0105834 pixel_height=0.0105834 voxel_depth=25.4000508 frame=[0 sec] origin=0,0");
            wait(2000);
            run("Analyze Particles...", "size=0.005-0.8 circularity=0.08-0.8 show=Nothing display exclude clear add");
            selectWindow("stack1");
            run("Select All");
            roiManager("Combine");

            //saveAs("Tiff", enddir);   
            selectWindow("Result of stack1");
            close();
            run("Collect Garbage");
            close();
            run("Collect Garbage");
            fileName = split(path[i-1],".");
            saveAs("Results", ""+enddir+""+fileName[0]+".xls");
            k=1;
            for (k=1; k<=5; k++) {
                run("Collect Garbage");
                call("CollectGarbage_.registerCloseListener");
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you post the macro code here, it is close to impossible to decide if that's a bug in Fiji or if there's something wrong with your macro (such as: not all images are being closed).

Comment: Sorry about that, the code is now there :)

Comment: The commands `Image Stabilizer` and `Hysteresis...` are not part of standard Fiji. Do you use this [Image Stabilizer plugin](http://fiji.sc/Image_Stabilizer)? I assume you manually installed the plugins? Why do you have these `wait()` statements? I suggest to start with a **minimal example** to debug where the memory leak might be. There's not much sense in calling `run("Collect Garbage");` all the time, it will be called automatically by Java when the heap is getting full (see [here](http://fiji.sc/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_avoid_running_out_of_memory_.28OutOfMemoryError.29.3F)).

Comment: Hello again, Yes that is the image stabilizer plug i use (I just got it from this link instead http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/People/kangli/code/Image_Stabilizer.html) I did install them manually yes. ok I will remove the wait timers and garbage collection. If I was to reduce into a minimal example, how can I determine is there is a memory leak or not? (since imageJ wont release its memory) Should I tackle one line at a time? or is that too far the other way (thanks for the help so far)